# MediaRecorder.setVideoSize() causes RuntimeException (start failed) at MediaRecorder.start()

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

When I attempt to set the video size for my MediaRecorder, I get a RuntimeException at the start method.

```
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
if (isVideo)
    mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
if (isVideo) {
    mRecorder.setVideoSize(480, 360); // Works fine when this is removed
    mRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
}

mRecorder.setOutputFile(newFilePath);

if (isVideo)
    mRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());

mRecorder.prepare();    // Prepare recorder
mRecorder.start();      // Start recording
```

Comment: Does the camera actually support that size?

Comment: Welp, possibly not. How would I go about ensuring the size is supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I've found to be the most elegant solution in my case:

```
CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
```

```
mRecorder.setVideoSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`getSupportedVideoSizes()` on `Camera.Parameters`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedVideoSizes%28%29) to get the supported video sizes. Cameras frequently cannot arbitrarily scale the image, presumably for performance reasons.

Comment: I updated my code with something I thought would work. Is getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo() not what I should be using? If so, how would I know which supported video size to use? Is the returned  list ordered from smallest to largest?

Comment: @JoshBjelovuk: "Is getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo() not what I should be using?" -- no. "If so, how would I know which supported video size to use?" -- your decision criteria is up to you. "Is the returned list ordered from smallest to largest?" -- I wouldn't count on it, but you can write a `Comparator` to help. I have one floating around in my CWAC-Camera library: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/blob/master/camera/src/com/commonsware/cwac/camera/CameraUtils.java#L192